# Как спрятать дебаг в консоли?

Tags: java, консоль, отладка, отладчик

Пример из консоли, проект создан на спринге, и по дефолту всегда показывает какой-то дебаг, в зависимости от того, работаю с хибернейтом, либо просто создаю бины -

```
    19:36:58.954 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4j2LoggerProvider
    19:36:58.968 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator].
    19:36:58.971 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccIntegrator].
    19:36:58.975 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cache.internal.CollectionCacheInvalidator].
    19:36:59.058 [main] INFO org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.11.Final}
    19:36:59.059 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    19:36:59.241 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver - Interpreting public/system identifier : [-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN] - [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd]
    19:36:59.242 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver - Recognized hibernate-configuration identifier; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
```

application.properties :

```
logging.level.ROOT=INFO
```

Полагаю, тут больше нет нужных конфигов?

[image]

Comment: Вы языком или сайтом ошиблись

Comment: @tym32167, нет, не ошибся. Начал изучать спринг, создал на нём проект (но сейчас его не трогаю, просто изучаю hibernate), а он по дефолту поставил такой дебаг

Comment: Тебе говорят о том, что ты на русскоязычном сайте. Потому вопросы задавать надо на русском.

Comment: @u_mulder, понял, спасибо

Comment: Как-то так наверно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847041/how-do-i-change-the-hibernate-logging-level?

Comment: @u_mulder, это затрагивает не только хибернейт, даже обычное создание бинов отображает. Прохожу курс Трегулова (Spring), и у него независимо от класса и метода дебага нет
(Ваша ссылка не помогла)

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Comment: @ArchDemon, да, это оно, но debug = false в application.properties не помогает

Comment: @KavasakMax loglevel поставить выше чем debug, например на уровень info

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо поднять уровень логировщика выше DEBUG например на INFO
Если у вас проект SpringBoot и отдельно нет конфигурации для логировщика, тогда в общем файле applicatioin.yml (или properties) повысить уровень логировщика для yml:

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
```

Для .properties:

```
logging.level.ROOT: INFO
```

Comment: Не знаю, может дело в конфигурации или ещё что? Где можно это посмотреть? Прописывая что либо в application.properties, который находится в resources root - ничего не меняется

Comment: выложи файл конфига в вопросе, и другие файлы конфигов если есть (logback.xml и тд)

Comment: Сделал, может есть что посмотреть в project structure?

Comment: Я вижу кто-то притащил зависимость Log4j2LoggerProvider а Spring Boot по-умолчанию логирует при помощи logback, поэтому он не реагирует на конфиги, попробуйте  `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO` и `logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO`

Comment: Удалил из зависимостей logback-classic:1.2.7 и logback-core:1.2.7 и всё сработало, дебага нет. Можешь объяснить, из-за зависимости Log4j2LoggerProvider не было реакции на конфиги?

Comment: Все логировщики в spring boot работают через фасад slf4j (небольшая абстракция над логировщиками, по задумке должна была помочь быстро менять логировщики без изменения кода), и по-умолчанию spring использует движок logback, соответственно и конфиги пробрасвает на него, но бывает что библиотеки притаскивают еще и свой логировщик до которых соответственно конфиги не доходят. Однако когда ты удалил "конфликты" т.е. оставил одного логировщика конфиги до него стали доходить. Можешь еще посмотреть видео "Владимир Красильщик — Что надо знать о логировании прагматичному Java-программисту"